# What is the device with a file name prefix of win?

Tags: metadata, filenames

I have some photos that were sent to me and I was intrigued with the device that was used to take them. However the the EXIF data it's of no help. I know that I have the original JPEG file, with a file name prefix of win (the full name is WIN_20160329_212328.JPG), and it's a 8MPx photo (3264x2448).

The original photo it's on https://www.dropbox.com/s/8gf7t20j6buh4ur/WIN_20160329_212328.JPG?dl=1

Can someone help me identify the family of devices (or even the device) used to take them?

Thanks.

Edit:

EXIF data

```
File
    File Type   JPEG
    File Type Extension jpg
    MIME Type   image/jpeg
    Exif Byte Order Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
    Comment Intel(R) IPP JPEG encoder [7.1.1]
    Image Width 3264
    Image Height    2448
    Encoding Process    Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
    Bits Per Sample 8
    Color Components    3
    Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling    YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
EXIF
    Orientation Horizontal (normal)
    Resolution Unit None
    Modify Date 2016:03:29 21:23:28
    Exposure Time   1/33
    F Number    2.2
    Exposure Program    Program AE
    ISO 328, 12338
    Exif Version    0220
    Date/Time Original  2016:03:29 21:23:28
    Create Date 2016:03:29 21:23:28
    Shutter Speed Value 1/33
    Brightness Value    0
    Exposure Compensation   0
    Metering Mode   Average
    Light Source    Unknown
    Flash   No Flash
    Flashpix Version    0100
    Color Space sRGB
    Offset Schema   312
JFIF
    JFIF Version    1.02
    X Resolution    1
    Y Resolution    1
Composite
    Aperture    2.2
    Shutter Speed   1/33
    Image Size  3264x2448
    Light Value 5.6
    Megapixels  8.0
```

Comment: Looks like the name is a timestamp: 2016-03-29  21:23:28.

Comment: The _Intel(R) IPP JPEG encoder [7.1.1]_ portion of the EXIF data makes me think a computer program created this file.  [Intel IPP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp) (Integrated Performance Primitives) is a commercial software library for use in computer programs and wouldn't be used in an embedded device like a camera.

Comment: my windows phones prefixed their images with Windows in the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cameras use the [DCF (Digital Camera File) standard](http://www.exif.org/dcf.PDF) which mandates that file and folder names fit the 8.3 format where each file or folder can have 8 letters/numbers (or certain other characters), a full-stop, then 3 more.  The file name is not compliant and was probably applied afterwards so it is not a useful signal in determining the device that produced the image.

Since the metadata has been stripped there is no additional information beyond the device being likely to be an 8mp camera as you've already worked out.

While there are tools to examine the encoding, the odds of being able to reliably get more information from what's given is limited as it was probably shot as a raw file and converted into a jpeg outside the camera.

Comment: This style of filename is quite common particularly from phone cameras (even within the /dcim/100dev folder structure).

Answer (score 3):

As this style of file naming is quite common in phone cameras, I'm going to hazard a guess that it came from such a device. 8Mpix seems reasonable for this. My Sony phone uses a more conventional naming scheme as shot but a format rather like this if I edit on the phone (the date in that case is the edit date)

Going a step further, how about a windows phone? I don't know anyone who's got one well enough to test.

Can you post the exif data anyway? On my Sony at least, the editor preserves it, though it's not *very* helpful.

The EXIF date/time matches the filename, the rest of the EXIF data looks like it's been cleaned of identifying information.  The fields that have been cleared aren't exactly the same ones windows 7 clears with its option to "Remove Properties and Personal information", but there's a lot of overlap.

Comment: I will post the EXIF data later, but it's embedded on the photo linked above. On the windows phone, the file name prefix seems to be WP_ so shouldn't be one of theses devices...

Comment: To get the file to download, changing the link to end with `?dl=1` works better.  I was on mobile earlier and couldn't get at it easily.

Comment: Whatever it is, it shoots video as well: search for WIN_20160101_000000, and images from it seem to often be uploaed to various sites on wikia.  Unfortuantely a few searches along those lines and google doesn't like me.

Comment: Individual apps on Windows Phone can name image files any way they want (WhatsApp appears to use "IMG-" as a prefix, for example)

Comment: @dav1dsm1th that's not surprising. I was guessing about a standard app (Samsung androids copy to a similar filename when emailing under certain circumstances).

Answer (score 2):

[JPEGsnoop](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-snoop.html) compares the compression signature in a JPEG with its database of known signature/software combinations, and gives a list of software that matches the signature of the input image. I just tried it with this image, and JPEGsnoop 1.7.0 gave me:

```
*** Searching Compression Signatures ***

  Signature:           013BA18D5561625796E986FDBC09F846
  Signature (Rotated): 01AC57E12793DFA7C46C704625C5AF0F
  File Offset:         0 bytes
  Chroma subsampling:  2x2
  EXIF Make/Model:     NONE
  EXIF Makernotes:     NONE
  EXIF Software:       NONE

  Searching Compression Signatures: (3347 built-in, 0 user(*) )

          EXIF.Make / Software        EXIF.Model                            Quality           Subsamp Match?
          -------------------------   -----------------------------------   ----------------  --------------
     CAM:[???                      ] [Treo 680                           ] [                ] Yes              
     CAM:[Canon                    ] [Canon PowerShot Pro1               ] [fine            ] No               
     CAM:[NIKON                    ] [E2500                              ] [FINE            ] No               
     CAM:[NIKON                    ] [E3100                              ] [FINE            ] No               
     CAM:[NIKON                    ] [E4500                              ] [FINE            ] No               
     CAM:[NIKON                    ] [E5000                              ] [FINE            ] No               
     CAM:[NIKON                    ] [E5700                              ] [FINE            ] No               
     CAM:[NIKON                    ] [E775                               ] [FINE            ] No               
     CAM:[NIKON                    ] [E885                               ] [FINE            ] No               
     CAM:[OLYMPUS OPTICAL CO.,LTD  ] [C3040Z                             ] [                ] No               
     CAM:[PENTAX                   ] [PENTAX Optio 550                   ] [                ] No               
     CAM:[Research In Motion       ] [BlackBerry 9530                    ] [Superfine       ] Yes              
     CAM:[SEIKO EPSON CORP.        ] [PhotoPC 3000Z                      ] [                ] No               
     CAM:[SONY                     ] [DSC-H7                             ] [                ] No               
     CAM:[SONY                     ] [DSC-H9                             ] [                ] No               
     CAM:[SONY                     ] [DSC-S90                            ] [                ] No               
     CAM:[SONY                     ] [DSC-W1                             ] [                ] No               
     CAM:[SONY                     ] [SONY                               ] [                ] No               
     SW :[ACDSee                   ]                                       [                ]                  
     SW :[FixFoto                  ]                                       [fine            ]                  
     SW :[IJG Library              ]                                       [090             ]                  
     SW :[ZoomBrowser EX           ]                                       [high            ]                  

    The following IJG-based editors also match this signature:
     SW :[GIMP                     ]                                       [090             ]                  
     SW :[IrfanView                ]                                       [090             ]                  
     SW :[idImager                 ]                                       [090             ]                  
     SW :[FastStone Image Viewer   ]                                       [090             ]                  
     SW :[NeatImage                ]                                       [090             ]                  
     SW :[Paint.NET                ]                                       [090             ]                  
     SW :[Photomatix               ]                                       [090             ]                  
     SW :[XnView                   ]                                       [090             ]                  

  Based on the analysis of compression characteristics and EXIF metadata:

  ASSESSMENT: Class 1 - Image is processed/edited

  This may be a new software editor for the database.
  If this file is processed, and editor doesn't appear in list above,
  PLEASE ADD TO DATABASE with [Tools->Add Camera to DB]
```